Button Loader work on desktop on mobile phone not working
why does this code not work on mobile phone but runs normally on desktop? So on mobile, the loader doesn't work and doesn't show up, while on desktop it works fine.
HTML:
<button class="wpfButton">Filter</button>

CSS:
.wpfButton {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.button--loading::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: button-loading-spinner 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0turn);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}

JS
const theButton = document.querySelector(".wpfButton");
theButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    theButton.classList.add("button--loading");
});


